# Unable to start connection in winform client

Tags: c#, winforms, signalr

I using `signalr` to implement a chat application.
However, I get the following error:

> `An exception of type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HttpClientException'
>
> occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal
>   Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent,
>   Headers:
>
> {
>
> Date: Fri, 21 Aug 2015 07:22:52 GMT
>
> Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> }

I dont know why. I am using signalR version 2.2.0
Here is my Hub

```
class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(message);
    }
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected: " + Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

Here is my `Startup class`

```
class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

My Server Program

```
class Program
{
    const string url = "http://localhost:8080";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebApp.Start(url);
        Console.WriteLine("Started server at " + url);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

My function in client winform

```
private async void AsyncConnect()
    {
        Connection = new HubConnection(url);
        chatProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");

        chatProxy.On<string>("addMessage", message =>
         txtMessageShow.Text += message + Environment.NewLine);

        await Connection.Start();
    }
```

Comment: What type do you give to  `Connection` and to  `chatProxy` ? Also, what does  `url` contain? Is it the same as the one fom  `const string url`?

Comment: I assign `HubConnection connection`, `IHubProxy chatProxy` and the url is `const string url ="http://localhost:8080"`

Comment: First of all, C# is case sensitive, so you can't have confusion between  `Connection` and  `connection`. Second, the  `url` should be  `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: Yep, my `HubConnection Connection`, and the `url` is `http://localhost:8080` in my code.

Comment: You call the `addMessage` client method on your hub, but you listen for `SendMessage` in your client. (Your code won't  work, though I don't believe it is causing your exception)

Comment: Yes, thank for this tip, I have changed it to `addMessage`.However, the first error is still coming.

Comment: Follow this precisely (run exacfly the sample they provide) and see if you still have the error  (to decide wether it is an error in your code  or you don't have the necesary libraries)  [Example from Microsoft](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b)

Answer (score 0):

Your Hub Proxy is invoking the Signalr pipeline before it has finished connecting. Please put an event handler while debugging to check confirmation of connection state. 
`hubConnection.StateChanged += (e) => { Debug.WriteLine(e.NewState)};`